# Replacing 84" entry door with 80" door

Tags: doors

I have 2 entry doors I need to replace, sized 32"x84" and 36"x84".  Each door also has a storm door, also 84" in height so I either have to get custom doors or replace the storm doors with standard sizes as well.  Is it possible to replace an 84" door with a standard door?  What would be involved in reducing the size of the rough opening?  Lastly, how would I 'hide' the resulting gap on the exterior of the house?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of siding do you have?

Comment: An 84" door gives a more spacious entrance than an 80" door. There are 84" doors available, you don't need a custom door.

Comment: Find a real door supplier (not a big box). You'll be able to get 84" doors for not too much extra. The minor upcharge will be more than offset by the time/effort/aesthetic problems.

Answer (score 1):

Many suppliers offer standard doors with 32" x 84" and 36" x 84" slabs. See for example these [ProVia specs](https://d2ucrk9xvdp3uo.cloudfront.net/pdf/Entry%20Door%20Sizing.pdf). **The best solution is to find a door supplier that will sell and install an 84" door.**

Yes, it is possible to reframe for a smaller door but the cost and complexity will go up dramatically. And the end result is unlikely to be architecturally pleasing. To a limited extent we can cover up the shorter framing with molding. But we would be talking about a 6-7" molding: 86" original RO minus 80" new FO. Don't do it. Put the money into a more spacious entry door. Your taller friends will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not just the matter of “hiding the gap” at the top of the door. If you use the shorter doors, you’ll also need to: 1) get smaller screen doors, 2) get smaller (shorter) door frame, and 3) adjust the inside and outside wall finish to cover the gap at the head.

I’d spend my money on getting new doors to match the original height, like @Stanwood said, and spend your money on 1) dapping the doors to match the hinge location, 2) drilling for locks to match existing strike location, and 3) prepping door for weatherstripping and threshold.